# How to protect our files from being overwritten in web hosting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp, decompiling

I have created a directory in my web hosting server .

I have created a text file.It is used for activation for my application.

But i have set username and password in my application. i wanted to test that decompilers really works or not for my application and it works. when i decompile my app it shows my username and password as it is. this is not good for me.If people knows my username and password they can overwrite the date file and increase the data for there subscription .

I dont want to give my files from being overwritten when someone opens the folder through filezilla .I want to give only download permission for my files not overwrite permission

There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should then set your FTP server so that the user under which your application logs in doesn't have write permissions.

If you're using plain FTP, it doesn't matter whether others will be able to decompile your application or not (and they will). They can just snoop their network communication and see the username and password.

Comment: i didnt give write permission but i am able to overwrite it through filezilla

Comment: If you are able to write to it through filezilla, then you have write permission.

Comment: i checked it but there is no write permission for my folder just read permission

Comment: @SharrokG that CANNOT be true since filezilla is not able to write except the server allows for that... check the permission setup for your user... your user is probably the owner of that file hence your user can overwrite it...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to setup security correctly - i.e. with the least needed permission set (your FTP directory shouldn't allow write for groups/world which it currently does according to what you describe!)...

As for the username/password decompilation problem - public key cryptography can help here:

- embed a public key into your app (or just distribute it openly with your app)
- this public key can be identical for all customers
- if you need to give a customer some spcial option you create an XML/text file...
- that file contains whatever you want in a format you define
- that file can contain anything in cleartext
- you sign that file (create the signature with your private key which is NEVER distributed)
- your app can verify the file is genuine by verifying the signature (for this it need the public key)
- if your app sends username/password over the network choose a protocol that thwarts snooping (for example server-side SSL, even better when combined with client-certificates)
- FTP can be used with SSL (called FTPS) or use somehting different like SFTP (part of SSH standard)

your customer can't create valid signatures based on the public key... if your hardware has some non-changeable serial number your app can read then I would put this hardware serial number into the XML/text file too... this way one XML/text file file can't be copied/used by different customers...

You can even extend this scheme by supplying customer specific public keys (and keeping the corresponding private keys private)... these can be distributed openly with the app without any need for hiding since the public key being known to anyone is not a security risk at all...

So if anyone ever overwrites/changes your file the signature will just be wrong thus making you safe from this sort of threat...

Ideally you sign your app/assembly (for this you need a certificate) which provides some security against tampering with your app/assembly then you have something really solid without need for any "tricks"...

Comment: @SharrokG in .NET there is for example XMLDocument class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)  to deal with XML... what I describe works with any file (XML or text file or whatever)...